# Is there an online engine like Google Scholar which allows me to sort the papers by citation count?

Tags: citations, google-scholar, reference-managers

I could not find a way of sorting the list of relevant publications on Google Scholar on the number of citations. It would help a lot as I prefer to start reading well-cited references before moving onto less cited and more recent ones.

I am not looking to use a reference manager as I look for papers in diverse fields, many of which I do not go into depth.

Comment: Web of Science certainly does, if you have access.

Comment: I do not have access to that.

Comment: Scopus is another example, if you have access.

Comment: download the list then sort in a relevant program.

Comment: Where do you get that list of publications from?  Google Scholar certainly sorts papers published by individual researchers by citation.

Comment: @SolarMike That's what I would do if such a program does not exist already.

Comment: If you are in a field that uploads to the arXiv, then the arXiv Bibliographic Explorer (https://labs.arxiv.org/) browser add-on may meet your needs. For any given paper, it can list all references and citations and sort by citation number.

Comment: @user151413 I could not determine a way to do it using Google Scholar.

Comment: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/20280/how-to-sort-google-scholar-search-results-by-number-of-citations  -- found an old related question pertaining to Google scholar

Comment: @kosmos Do you have affiliation with a university? If so, does that university have a decent library? If so, have you checked whether your library has access to WoS? It's possible that your library has subscribed to WoS or other resources and you may have access through your institution.

Comment: @shoover just graduated. access revoked.  :(

Comment: @kosmos ouch...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are at least four freely available databases which have this function. In random order:

1. **Lens**: In [Lens](https://www.lens.org/), instead of the default `Sort by Relevance` choose `Scholarly Citations (highest)`
2. **Microsoft Academic**: In [Microsoft Academic](https://academic.microsoft.com/home), choose `SORT BY MOST EST. CITATIONS`
3. **Dimensions**: In [Dimensions](https://app.dimensions.ai/discover/publication), choose `Sort by: Citations`
4. **ScienceOpen**: In [ScienceOpen](https://www.scienceopen.com/search), select `Sort by cited by count`