# Is there any way to find the most-cited papers that match a keyword?

Tags: citations, google-scholar

Let's say Google Scholar has a million matches for a certain keyword, but I only want to see the 100 most-cited ones. Is there any way to do this? (Note that "Sort by Relevance" doesn't accomplish this)

Comment: Pretty sure Web of Science lets you sort by citations.

Answer (score 1):

Not in Google Scholar. PubMed does not either. Both Scopus and WoS allow you to do that though. I'm not sure about other search engines or databases.

There was a similar question a few years ago: [Is there an online engine like Google Scholar which allows me to sort the papers by citation count?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/151977/is-there-an-online-engine-like-google-scholar-which-allows-me-to-sort-the-papers). I'm not sure how up-to-date it still is but Dimensions and ScienceOpen should still do what you need.